# HTTP not redirecting to HTTPS in HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

In need to figure out how I need to modify the code below to redirect the HTTP to HTTPS for this site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.website\-website\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.website\-website\.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/website\.website\-website\.org\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Probably because you are doing things in the wrong order. Such a redirect should always come before you do any internal rewrites.

Comment: And slapping `[OR]` on that second-to-last condition probably doesn't do what you think it should, it is still an implicit AND for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines just after `RewriteEngine On` and It will help you to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've tried this method and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Make sure that you have enabled `mod_rewrite` and set the `AllowOverride all` on apache / httpd